# How does .NET's Primary Interop Assembly Embedding work?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, com, interop, embedding

I am researching the .NET Common Language Infrastructure, and before I get into the nitty-gritty of the compiler I'm going to write, I want to be sure that certain features are available.  In order to do that, I must understand how they work.

One feature I'm unsure of is the .NET Primary Interop Assembly embedding.  I'm not quite sure how .NET goes about embedding only the types you use versus the types that are exposed by the types you use.  From the bit of research I've done into this, I've noticed that it emits a bare-bones interface that utilizes vtable gap methods, where the method name format is VtblGap{0}_{1} where {0} is the index of the gap and {1} is the member size of the gap.  These methods are marked rtspecialname and specialname. Whether this is accurate or not, is the question.

Assuming the above is true, how would I go about obtaining the necessary information to embed similar metadata into the resulted application?

From what I can tell, you can order the MemberInfo objects obtained via their metadata tokens for the order, and the dispid information is obtained via the attributes from the interop assembly.  The area I'm most confused on are the interfaces that are imported that seem to have no direct correlation with the other embedded types, sequentially indexed interfaces that seem to be there for versioning reasons.  Is their inclusion based off of their indexing or is there some other logic used?  An example is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, when you add a document to an Application and, in doing something with it, it imports the document, its events, and so on.

Here's hoping someone in-the-know can clue me in on what else might be involved in embedding these types.

Comment: From my SO experience, I don't think that you will get much answers. Instead, create a simple test that you think might be a blocking case for your project and ask it(if you can't manage it to work)

Comment: The blocking case is the fact that it's not really clear as to where the interfaces imported are coming from.  i.e. Why does it import ApplicationEvents, ApplicationEvents_Event, ApplicationEvents2, ApplicationEvents2_Event, ApplicationEvents3, ApplicationEvents3_Event, when the only ones directly referenced are ApplicationEvents4_Event and ApplicationEvents4.  You could assume the incremental nature of the interfaces was for versioning, but that's a pretty big leap without actually knowing.